# Cocos2d-x-2.2 for Android - create new project on Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've just started to work with Cocos2d-x. I've checked a lot of tutorials how to start this framework but this one was most helpful to me: http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/ and I belive it's still actual. I am working on Windows 7. I am able to start sample on emulator/device of any project situated in cocos2d-x by Linux simulator console (./build_native.sh with adding NKK_ROOT dir).

I have problem with starting my own work. All of the tutorials for Eclipse that I've seen said that you needed to run create-android-project shell file (some sources says its *.sh, others that it's *.bat file... I'm confused) but to be honest after downloading latest Cocos2d-x-2.2 I can't locate there any file that could help me to create my own, new project. I have downloaded my Cocos2d-x from this site: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download

1. So... if there is no create-android-project file to compile, how can I start my own work/create new project?
2. I have some samples (I'm interested in Cpp) like SimpleGame, CppHelloWorld which compile and work propely. I can't localize any *.cpp files to edit, any "main body" of the projects. On YT I saw that developers that use this framework usually store their game files in "Classes" folder, but mine (in sample of course) contains only compiled *.class files what makes them unable to edit. Is there any way to edit those projects? How can I access core files for project?

Please answer me at least for the 1st question it's very important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use sample projects like "HelloCpp" from the cocos2dx download, and rename all the stuffs out there about the project, and Add your classes as required in the Classes folder, add your assets into Resources folder, run build-native.sh after adding. Don't forget to add the list of c++ source files in the Makefile in the android project(in proj.android/jni/Android.mk file, originally there should be main.cpp and some sample file names). Let me know if you have any problems after this.

Comment: Okay... I downloaded Cocos2d-x 2.1.2 and there was create-android-project.sh file, but setting this environment from nothing kills me a bit. I'm going with your idea of editing HelloCpp. So far I have built HelloCpp's build_native.sh and imported the project to eclipse. Cleaned the errors by adding link source to cocos2dx/platform/java/src path. And now there is one confusing thing. In my project tree I can see three folders that I can't open:  Classes cocos2dx and extensions. You said to add Classes folder and assets into resources. Where can I locate Classes folder so I can add it?In sample?

Comment: After copying Classes folder to tree I'm able to use it and it doesn't have errors. But I can't build the project because I have error in Android.mk -> there are screens of code and console log: http://s9.postimg.org/o4l5cma1b/console.png , http://s23.postimg.org/uy05njtx7/screen.png . And should I copy to the project tree also other too unavaliable folders (cocos2dx and extensions)?

Comment: Have you defined NDK_ROOT environment variable in your system?? So that build_native.sh knows where is android ndk is located.

Comment: Yes it's defined in build_native.sh and that works fine because for the 1st time Sample was built and then I imported it and copied at once via Eclipse to other location. After doing it I can't build it again. And the console says that it's not problem with NDK_ROOT but NDK_MODULE_PATH but there was nothing about it in any tutorial so I don't even know what should This path be pointing at or where can I find it in files.

Comment: I can see NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source
line in the build_native.sh, so few lines above this line There you have  ${COCOS2DX_ROOT} definition. And it's defined relative. There you can define full path of COCOS2D_ROOT there, and then NDK_MODULE_ROOT path builds fine!
I can not see the error message in Android.mk in ADT! Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: COCOS2DX_ROOT and NDK_ROOT variables should be defined in Eclipse, Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Enviroment->Add

Comment: I've added environment variables (screen on it with also my folders structure: http://postimg.org/image/ioceq7zuf/ but it doesn't change anything. I think problem is somewhere else, because look at the warnings http://postimg.org/image/a5crrxg8n/ . It wants to import cocos2dx from E:/ dir but COCOS2DX root dir is compeletly different. I try to hardcode path somewhere but I'm currently having problems with it. And there is no description to error in Android.mk as u can see. I also hardcoded COCOS2DX_ROOT path in build_native.sh but nothing changed so I reversed it back.

Comment: I couldn't change that path (don't know why i didnt react) so I just moved cocos2dx to E:/ for now. Warning disapeared but still it doesnt work... check this: http://postimg.org/image/97czkggk1/  I have modified COCOS2DX_ROOT in build_native.sh, there is alos Environment Variable but still in Build console he points compeletly different dir :/

Comment: Just remove original variables from eclipse (COCOS2DX_ROOT and NDK_ROOT) and make new ones with the correct path that you've shown in the imagehttp://postimg.org/image/ioceq7zuf/full/ 
Eclipse will take  these variables to build. I've faced same error today, and I did the same and it should work. Don't forget to comment out line number 54 in build_native.sh, as there is hard-coded relative path for COCOS2DX_ROOT, which will cause the wrong path for cocos2dx
 Don't run from console for now, for console you have to set environment variables to the windows system itself.

Comment: I don't quite understand. "remove original variables from eclipse" you mean those in environment variables? And then add them again?

Comment: Well... okay after commenting 54th lane it compiles without errors. But on build I get E:/Projects/Gra/GameWorkSpace/HelloCpp/build_native.sh: line 97: syntax error: unexpected end of file (last lane in build_native.sh)

Comment: The file should end with text "fi" at the last line, and no more [ENTER] after the last line of the code in build_native.sh.

Comment: There is "fi" at end. There was 97th lane but I have deleted it and now it's only 96. Still I get error with eof in 97th lane. Screen of this: http://postimg.org/image/oolw2zxzp/  and I've also highlighted commented lane with COCOS2DX_ROOT just in case. In general project builds on device but crashes instantly.

Comment: Ehh okay. Thanks for help and patience but I don't think I will be able to set this framework. Insane amount of errors, I got dizzy.

Comment: I started over... but inside sample, I didn't copy it to other workspace. At least I can try to edit sth and learn. I think I will instal Linux, I read it's easier to use this framework here. Anyway, I asked question how can I start my own project, you told me to edit sample -> I'm doing it.

Comment: It seems the problem with Windows, as you're editing build_native.sh in windows, and new line character is understood by windows differently and the build_native.sh is shell script! You better setup everything in linux/mac. That would be better!

Answer (score 1):

There's a create_project.py in tools folder, which can create multi-platform project for you in projects folder, you can copy the project and put anywhere you like, although you normally need to change few settings, before it'll run. And yes running `build_native.sh` is compulsary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a multiplatform project then use this command after navigating to the following directory yourdrive:\cocos2dxparentfolder\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\tools\project-creator

./create_project.py -project yourprojectname -package com.yourcompany.yourprojectname -language cpp

You can use any convention for package name, not necessarily com.yourcompany.yourprojectname

On windows you may use command prompt for performing all of the above